# window.getSelection on a jquery ui dialog does not return selection in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, getselection

I am using the jquery UI dialog ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ ) to display a chunk of text. I want to select some text on this dialog box and manipulate it. Now my current code works on Chrome and Firefox but is not working on Safari. (Not tested on IE yet)

I get the selection and display it as follows:

```
selection = window.getSelection(); 
alert(selection.toString().length);
```

The alert returns zero on Safari. I am relatively new to javascript/jquery so any pointers will help! Thank you!

Answer: For anyone seeing this... when I used the event "mousedown" instead of "click" in the dialog box on safari it started working. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I opened the demo page you linked to in Safari, selected some text in the dialog and ran `alert(window.getSelection().toString())` in the JavaScript console and it worked as expected. Could you provide more details and/or a demo page showing the problem?

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: The version of Safari that I have is: Version 5.0.5 (6533.21.1)

Comment: Hi Tim, that works for me too! The only difference then between my code and the demo code is that my text is input into the dialog programmatically whereas the demo has it in a <p> tag.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Safari works a little differently. The getSelection() is not returning a normal string object so not all the string methods work on the object it returns. This link has a work around http://joemaller.com/503/getselection-workaround/

It looks like it is a very old "bug" so there may be better advise on what to do instead out there.

Comment: So the object I get is not "undefined" it just comes back empty. Maybe I am not looking at the correct object for a dialog?

Comment: Safari has supported `window.getSelection()` in a similar way to other browsers since version 3. Version 2.0 and earlier are used by so few people that they can be safely ignored for most sites, so your link is unlikely to be relevant to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing anything with selections, I would **strongly** recommend that you take a look at Tim Down's ***[rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/)*** library. This guy is the Range/Selection object guru. His library does all the nitty gritty work of implementing a cross-browser range selection library. The documentation is good and he is actively working on the project (v 1.1 came out a few days ago).

(edit: I am NOT affiliated with the project. I just use it and love it!)

Comment: I don't know if I need something that is that extensive. The text that I am going to have is clean text, without any html tags in there. I had the same code working smoothly in an overlay, but now in a dialog it is not working in safari. I just might be a line of code away :( Do you know if I can access an individual element, and look for selections within it?